# Tips on how to create box whisker plot for huge data set

Tags: visualization

I have a huge dataset (about 2 million lines) that I want to visualize to have an idea of how spread the data is. The problem now is when I create a box whisker plot the resulting graph is not legible due to the huge amount of data.

Is there any trick to be able to successfully create a box whisker plot for huge data set in the way that is readable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope you are aware of data sampling methods. They exist to solve problems such as these. They are of several types like;

**Probability Sampling Methods**

1. Simple random sampling
2. Systematic sampling
3. Stratified sampling
4. Clustered sampling

**Non-Probability Sampling Methods**

1. Convenience sampling
2. Quota sampling
3. Judgement (or Purposive) Sampling
4. Snowball sampling

When sampling the data, be careful of the `bias`.

**Bias in sampling**

There are five important potential sources of bias that should be considered when selecting a sample, irrespective of the method used. Sampling bias may be introduced when:

1. Any pre-agreed sampling rules are deviated from
2. People in hard-to-reach groups are omitted
3. Selected individuals are replaced with others, for example if they are difficult to contact
4. There are low response rates
5. An out-of-date list is used as the sample frame (for example, if it excludes people who have recently moved to an area)

Basis of the above detail, I think there is no need to use the entire dataset for visualization purpose. Consider an example, each country conducts a census survey to estimate its population of people. Such a dataset is huge both in size and in complexity. Do you think those statisticians use the complete dataset for visualization? I strongly doubt it. They use sampling methods.

**Edit**

**Python Code**

```
# load required libraries
import pandas as pd
# create some dummy data
df = pd.DataFrame({'num_legs': [2, 4, 8, 0],
                   'num_wings': [2, 0, 0, 0],
                   'num_specimen_seen': [10, 2, 1, 8]},
                  index=['falcon', 'dog', 'spider', 'fish'])
print("## Original data ##\n",df)

## Original data ##
         num_legs  num_wings  num_specimen_seen
falcon         2          2                 10
dog            4          0                  2
spider         8          0                  1
fish           0          0                  8
```

Sampling methods:

1. Simple random sampling: Extract 3 random rows

```
    print("\n Simple random sample")
    print(df.sample(3, random_state=10))
    Simple random sample
            num_legs  num_wings  num_specimen_seen
    spider         8          0                  1
    falcon         2          2                 10
    fish           0          0                  8
```

1.1. Simple random sampling: Extract 3 random elements from the Series

```
df['num_legs']
print("\n Simple random sample of particular column\n",df['num_legs'].sample(n=3, random_state=10))
 
Simple random sample of particular column
spider    8
falcon    2
fish      0
Name: num_legs, dtype: int64
```

1.2. Random sampling with replacement

```
print("\nA random 50% sample of the DataFrame with replacement:")
print(df.sample(frac=0.5, replace=True, random_state=10))
A random 50% sample of the DataFrame with replacement:
     num_legs  num_wings  num_specimen_seen
dog         4          0                  2
dog         4          0                  2
```

1.3. Random upsampling with replacement

```
print("\nAn upsample sample of the DataFrame with replacement")
print(df.sample(frac=2, replace=True, random_state=10))
An upsample sample of the DataFrame with replacement
        num_legs  num_wings  num_specimen_seen
dog            4          0                  2
dog            4          0                  2
falcon         2          2                 10
fish           0          0                  8
falcon         2          2                 10
dog            4          0                  2
fish           0          0                  8
falcon         2          2                 10
```

1.4. Random sampling with weights

```
print("\nUsing a DataFrame column as weights. Rows with larger value in the num_specimen_seen column are more likely to be sampled.")
print(df.sample(n=2, weights='num_specimen_seen', random_state=10))
# Using a DataFrame column as weights. Rows with larger value in the num_specimen_seen column are more likely to be sampled.
        num_legs  num_wings  num_specimen_seen
fish           0          0                  8
falcon         2          2                 10
```

2. Stratified Random Sampling

```
    print("\nStratified Random Sampling")
    print(df.groupby('num_legs', group_keys=False).apply(lambda x:x.sample(min(len(x), 2))))
```

```
Stratified Random Sampling

        num_legs  num_wings  num_specimen_seen
fish           0          0                  8
falcon         2          2                 10
dog            4          0                  2
spider         8          0                  1
```

This brief example should get you started!

Comment: thanks for mentioning data sampling...i am sort of aware of it but it never crossed my mind as a technique i could use. I go and look into how i can use it....but in the meantime if you know of concrete ways I an do this working with pandas do share :)

Comment: @FinlayWeber have revised the answer.